# How to add variable name on a python tk.entry made in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a form with repetitive user input so i made the entry boxes using a for loop. However assigning them a unique variable name isn't possible. For example:

```py
for n in range(10):
    tk.Entry().grid(row = 0, column = n)
```

Is there any way to have it be assigned to a variable automatically or I should make all 10 entry box with a variable name manually?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the Entry's in a list?

Comment: No reason. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a list like this:

```
entries = []
for n in range(10):
    entries.append(tk.Entry())
    entries[n].grid(row = 0, column = n)
```

and later access the entries by index...

Comment: The values in the list only shows <Entry object> but not the values entered.

Comment: @milinile, you have to call `.get()` on the list items to get the contents, exactly as you would if you had assigned each Entry to a separate variable.